# Woocommerce product gallery crop images

Tags: woocommerce, divi

Images displayed in low quality and cropped when gallery on grid mode, and Divi settings do not got configuration for images. How it can be displayed on vertical display in full width with different orientation (horizontal images now hiden)

Displayed on page

[image: 1]

Full image

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happening because of different plugins for WooCommerce gallery, that although change slider code and broke displaying.